# how turn on flashlight when use camera ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am currently using the camera Preview plugin in ionic 3, I have created a button to activate the flashlight plugin but when calling the method it returns `null`

```
 if (this.flashlight.available()) {
       this.isOn = false;
       this.flashlight.isSwitchedOn() ? this.flashlight.switchOff() : this.flashlight.switchOn();
     } else {
       alert('Flashlight Not Available');
     }
```

I want to have that button to use the flash as a flashlight while I using the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setFlashMode` Method to set flash status

```
  flashMode = 'on';
  changeFlashMode() {
   this.cameraPreview.setFlashMode(this.flashMode);
  }
```

you can see this full article that do what you want to do from [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-camera-preview-floating-camera-view-in-page-tutorial/)

Comment: `flashMode = 'torch'` work for me!